# How to set CORS in KeystoneJSv4

Tags: keystonejs

I have a VueJS application running on a server other than KeystoneJS.
I would like to send requests from the VueJS applications to Keystone.

How do I activate CORS in version 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your index file, first set your CORS config, like origin, header and methods:

```
// example for allow all
keystone.set('cors allow origin', true);
keystone.get('cors allow methods', true)
keystone.get('cors allow methods', headers)
```

Then you need to apply the config for your routes in your route files.

Apply CORS to all routes:

```
app.all('/*', keystone.middleware.cors);
```

Apply CORS to a specific `/about` route:

```
app.all('/about', keystone.middleware.cors);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I had not applied CORS to routes! It works perfectly.

Comment: Just read the last one should be as well keystone.get('cors allow methods', true)

Answer (score 0):

Simply put the following code in **routes/index.js**

```
app.use('*', function (req, res, next) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        next();
    });
    app.options('*', function (req, res) {
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, X-XSRF-TOKEN');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Method', 'GET,POST,PUT,DELETE');
        res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
        res.sendStatus(200);
    });
```